# Is Nginx supports Request Log Analyzer(RLA)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, rubygems

I want to know is Nginx proxy server supports the Request Log Analyzer(RLA) gem in ruby?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick look at the [Docs of the RLA](https://github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer/wiki):

First answer would be **yes**.

Quick tryout with an nginx (1.4.4) error log:

```
request-log-analyzer error.log --format nginx
# => No usable output
```

Quick try with an **access.log**:

```
request-log-analyzer access.log --format nginx
# => actually usable output
```

I tried with JRuby 1.7.8 as the ruby running the script, no promises for other rubies, though.